# Combining two Numpy matrices containing arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two matrices (m1 and m2) with sizes 125, 30, 360 that contain arrays with different lengths. What I want to do is to concatenate those arrays element-wise. For now, I do this with for loops:

```
for i in range(125):
    for j in range(30):
        for k in range(360):
            m1[i, j, k] = np.hstack(m1[i, j, k], m2[i, j, k])
```

So the resulting `m1` still has the same size as before, however, the arrays in each element have changed length. The above example works but it takes a long time (I do this many times in my code). Is there a quicker way to do it? `m1` and `m2` are created as follows if that clarifies things:

```
m1 = np.zeros([125, 30, 360], dtype=np.ndarray)
for i in range(125):
    for j in range(30):
        for k in range(360):
            m1[i,j,k] = np.array([])
```

EDIT: My text above was a little bit unclear, which has lead to some confusion. I have therefore created a small example below of what I want to do.

Step 1: Create m1 and m2.

```
m1 = np.zeros([2, 2], dtype=np.ndarray)
m2 = np.zeros([2, 2], dtype=np.ndarray)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        m1[i, j] = np.array(range(i+j))
        m2[i, j] = np.array(range(i+j+1))
```

Step 1 results in:

```
m1 = array([[array([], dtype=float64), array([0])],
  [array([0]), array([0, 1])]], dtype=object)
m2 = array([[array([0]), array([0, 1])],
  [array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

Step 2: Concatenate m1 and m2.

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        m1[i, j] = np.hstack((m1[i, j], m2[i, j]))
```

Step 2 results in:

```
m1 = array([[array([ 0.]), array([0, 0, 1])],
  [array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

So, the question is: Can step 2 be done faster?

Comment: How can it have same size but different length? Add a minmal sample case?

Comment: I mean that m1.shape = 125,30,360 both before and after the for loops. But the arrays inside the m1 will change size. If, for example, m1[10, 10, 10] has the length 5 and the m2[10, 10, 10] has the length 7 before the for loops the resulting m1[10, 10, 10] will have the length 12. Hope this clarify what I meant.

Comment: Why is `m1` a 3d object dtype array as opposed to a list?  (Correct the 'arrayer' typo)

Comment: Sorry @hpaulj I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: `np.ndarray` is not a dtype. Remove that.

Comment: ...wait, what the heck are you doing? `np.ndarray` still isn't a dtype, but for some reason, you really are making arrays with arrays inside. Why are you doing that?

Comment: You've chosen a really weird way to structure your data, and it's not one NumPy was designed to make easy or efficient. `for` loops are going to be your best bet for most operations with these arrays.

Comment: Yes, I realize that this isn't the best way to structure data. This is what happens when you take some old code that was designed for something else and try to adapt it to something new, in a way to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [164]: m1 = np.zeros([2, 2], dtype=np.ndarray)
     ...: m2 = np.zeros([2, 2], dtype=np.ndarray)
     ...: for i in range(2):
     ...:     for j in range(2):
     ...:         m1[i, j] = np.array(range(i+j))
     ...:         m2[i, j] = np.array(range(i+j+1))
     ...:
```

The result is 2 2d arrays of dtype object.  `dtype=np.ndarray` becomes `object` for anything that isn't in the defined set of `dtypes`.

```
In [165]: m1
Out[165]: 
array([[array([], dtype=float64), array([0])],
       [array([0]), array([0, 1])]], dtype=object)
In [166]: m1.shape
Out[166]: (2, 2)
In [167]: m2.shape
Out[167]: (2, 2)
In [168]: m1[0,0]
Out[168]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

`m1` is then a 2d array that contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.  In your case they are arrays, but they could be lists, dicts, `None`, strings or numbers or even functions.

Such array could be described as a glorified list, since it has shape (2d), can be reshaped, and in a few cases it will even project math operations down to the elements (e.g. `m1*2`).  Or it could be a debased list, since it doesn't have methods like `append`.

For the most part, `numpy` operations on such arrays require Python level iteration.  And with a 2d shape that requires a double loop, or the equivalent.

As with any nd array you can get around nested loops with flattening; for example with a list comprehension:

```
In [173]: [np.concatenate((a,b)) for a,b in zip(m1.flat, m2.flat)]
Out[173]: [array([ 0.]), array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2])]
In [174]: np.array([np.concatenate((a,b)) for a,b in zip(m1.flat, m2.flat)]).reshape(2,2)
Out[174]: 
array([[array([ 0.]), array([0, 0, 1])],
       [array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

This is a case where `frompyfunc` could be useful, taking care of the higher-dimensionality for you.  I've found that it provides a modest (2x at most) speed up over more explicit loops:

```
In [177]: f=np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: np.concatenate((a,b)),2,1)
In [178]: f(m1,m2)
Out[178]: 
array([[array([ 0.]), array([0, 0, 1])],
       [array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

In sum, any element wise operation on a object array will be slow compared to similar operations on a n-d numeric array.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Really well explained. In my case the nested loop was more than 5 times faster than the for loops while the frompyfunc didn't give any time saving.